# Can we enforce content-type validation in consumes of @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If we call a post API with JSON body and `content-type` header as `multipart/form-data` and set the `consumes` value as `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`, it gives 500 error instead of 400.

```java
@RestController
public class AppController {
  @PostMapping(value = "/test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  ResponseEntity get(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

response

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2024-03-14T10:16:06.059+00:00",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:86)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:112)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1219)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)\r\nCaused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2843)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2700)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:774)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:93)\r\n\t... 43 more\r\nCaused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.init(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:189)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.getMultiPartStream(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:205)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:224)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileItemIteratorImpl.<init>(FileItemIteratorImpl.java:142)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:252)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:276)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2799)\r\n\t... 46 more\r\n",
    "message": "Failed to parse multipart servlet request",
    "path": "/test"}
```

Comment: Here's your explanation
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27445